# InstallShield Version

Tags: installshield, installshield-le

I am trying to determine which version of InstallShield I need. I need to be able to move files from one folder to another folder during the install. Then during the uninstall, I need to be able to remove those files.

I am not sure which version I would need? Premiere or Professional?

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom actions to do the behavior you want in both Professional and Premiere. However, there may be some other feature that you absolutely need that Premiere may only contain. To be sure, you can look at the features here: http://www.flexerasoftware.com/producer/products/software-installation/installshield-software-installer/tab/editions